# Running databrew.describe_job_run() from inside a Lambda does not work

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, aws-glue

I have a Lambda that polls the status of a DataBrew job using a boto3 client. The code - as written here - works fine in my local environment. When I put it into a Lambda function, I get the error:

`[ERROR] AttributeError: 'GlueDataBrew' object has no attribute 'describe_job_run'`

This is the syntax found in the [Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/databrew.html#GlueDataBrew.Client.describe_job_run):

```
client.describe_job_run(
    Name='string',
    RunId='string')
```

This is my code:

```
import boto3

def get_brewjob_status(jobName, jobRunId):
    brew = boto3.client('databrew')

    try:
        jobResponse = brew.describe_job_run(Name=jobName, RunId=jobRunId)
        status = jobResponse['State']
        
    except Exception as e:
        status='FAILED'
        print('Unable to get job status')
        raise(e)

    return {
        'jobStatus':status
    }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    jobName=event['jobName']
    jobRunId=event['jobRunId']
    response=get_brewjob_status(jobName, jobRunId)
    
    return response
```

I am using the Lambda runtime version of boto3. The jobName and jobRunId variables are strings passed from a Step Function, but I've also tried to hard code them into the Lambda to check the error and I get the same result. I have tried running it on both the runtime Python3.7 and Python3.8 versions. I'm also confident (and have double checked) that the IAMs permissions allow the Lambda access to DataBrew. Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own problem. There must be some kind of conflict with the boto3 runtime and databrew - maybe not updated to include databrew yet? I created a .zip deployment package and it worked fine. Should have done that two days ago...